# 403 forbidden for nova admin on production site with forge

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a new project up with forge. I changed my admin column in the user table, but I get 403 forbidden when trying to log in. Why do I get this when I didn't on the devsite? Do I have to install nova in the forge command? or is there some files I have forgotten to configurate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `local` application environments, any user can access Laravel Nova.

However, when accessing `non-local` application environments, you have to explicitly authorize users to access Laravel Nova. This is all described in the [Installation section](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/installation.html#customizing-nova-s-authentication-guard) of the Laravel Nova documentation.

In your `app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php` file, there is a gate method. You can simply add your email to the `in_array` function there. Or alternatively, you can create a method like `isAdmin()` on user, to determine if the user is an admin. You would have to create additional logic for that (either add a `is_admin` boolean column to your User model, or full Role-Based Access Control).

**NovaServiceProvider.php**

```
/**
 * Register the Nova gate.
 *
 * This gate determines who can access Nova in non-local environments.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function gate()
{
    Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
        return in_array($user->email, [
            // add your email here
        ]);
    });

    // or alternatively

    Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
        return $user->isAdmin();
    });
}
```

Comment: yeah I figured it out. I already had a isAdmin middleware and thought it was supposed to be enough. I forgot about adding the email part